How to add seed data using graphQL mutations in Firebase Data Connect
I have a self-referencing schema:
type Category @table(name: "Categories", singular: "category", plural: "categories", key: ["id"]) {
  id: UUID! @default(expr: "uuidV4()")
  name: String!
  description: String
  active: Boolean
  parent: Category @hasInverse(field: "children")
  children: [Category]
}

In my mutation file Category_insert.gql, I have the following mutation:
mutation {
  category_insertMany(
    data: [
      {id: "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555", active: false, description: "", name: "Clothing & Accessories"},
      {
        id: "22222222-3333-4444-5555-666666666666", 
        parent: {id: "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555"}, 
        active: false, 
        description: "", 
        name: "Adult Clothing"
      } ...

Now, I've played around with the syntax, so I've tried this as well...
type Category @table(name: "Categories", singular: "category", plural: "categories", key: ["id"]) {
  id: UUID! @default(expr: "uuidV4()")
  name: String!
  description: String
  active: Boolean
  parent: Category @ref
}

And in my mutation file I've tried this:
mutation {
  category_insertMany(
    data: [
      {id: "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555", active: false, description: "", name: "Clothing & Accessories"},
      {
        id: "22222222-3333-4444-5555-666666666666", 
        parentId: "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555", 
        active: false, 
        description: "", 
        name: "Adult Clothing"
      } ...

The most common error I am seeing when I run:

Run (local)**, while running the firebase emulator, is **mutation, , category_insertMany (data[1]: [Category_Data!]!): misaligned columns: extra parentId

I am not that familiar with graphQL and am just learning the new Firebase Data Connect service so any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

I was able to get it working. I had to change my mutation file.
mutation {
  category_insert(
    data: {id: "2709c745-34c5-495d-9c89-85c4402350bf", active: false, description: "", name: "Home & Garden"}
  )

  category_insertMany(
    data: [
      {
        id: "22222222-3333-4444-5555-666666666666", 
        parent: {id: "2709c745-34c5-495d-9c89-85c4402350bf"}, 
        active: false, 
        description: "", 
        name: "Adult Clothing"
      }

In my original question, I was trying to add the parent category and children categories in the same _insertMany mutation.
So under the hood, graphql needed the parent record created first, then create the child records.   After I made the above modification this mutation worked (I verified it in the database)
